# Best link to forward to juniors re: correct use of apostrophes, possessives and contractions

Tags: grammar, possessives, apostrophe

I'm tired of my junior employees abusing, misusing and otherwise being cavalier about possessives and the use of apostrophes. I could wag my finger at them, point them to some Guide of Style or to any of a myriad of pedantic websites that come up in a simple Google Search.

What I'm looking for specifically is a good writeup, whose intended target audience is this younger generation who seem to neither know, nor care, much about grammar (nor spelling for that matter, but I digress).

If the article is humorous, or even sarcastic, so much the better. The goal is to make sure a young blase audience reads it through to the end, and retains the salient points.

Throw up your links, fellow pedants!

Tom

Comment: Hey, young people aren't all like that (case in point myself...)!

Comment: Let me introduce you to Bob the Angry Flower: [one](http://angryflower.com/bobsqu.gif), [two](http://www.angryflower.com/itsits.gif). However, I am not posting this as an answer because I'm not sure if the question is actually on-topic for this site.

Comment: Yeah, I was concerned about the "topicity" (?) of this post as well. Then I decided that there was nowhere else I'd rather post this question so proceeded to ask it here anyway. Thanks for Bob!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I love a comic by The Oatmeal called, "[How To Use An Apostrophe](http://theoatmeal.com/comics/apostrophe)."

This is a fun, light (a little humorous) way to teach about the problems you mentioned above.

Comment: Awesome. And since my team is composed entirely of graphic designers, this one gets bonus marks for its really nice layout.